# JavaScript doesn't execute if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am writing a simple game and can't understand why my if block doesn't work. When I click button check it executes just first if statement block, please could you help my to understand why. Here is my code.

```
const checkBtn = document.querySelector(".check");
const guessInput = Number(document.querySelector(".guess").value);
const againBtn = document.querySelector(".again");
const message = document.querySelector(".message");
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
const secretNumber = document.querySelector(".secret-number");
console.log(randomNumber);

secretNumber.textContent = randomNumber;

checkBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (!guessInput) {
    message.textContent = "No Number!";
    console.log("no number");
  } else if (guessInput === randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = "Correct!";
    console.log("correct");
  } else if (guessInput > randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = "Too high!";
    console.log("too high");
  } else if (guessInput < randomNumber) {
    message.textContent = "Too low";
    console.log("too low");
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The if statement is working correctly, you just need to update the `guessInput` value. Currently you only get the `guessInput` value when the page loads. Try adding `guessInput = Number(document.querySelector(".guess").value);` withing your addEventListener function and it will likely work for you.

Comment: you need to move the getting of the value of input into the function

Comment: So I should assign to the variable inside of the function?

Comment: @NinaScholz is always right!  Change `const guessInput = ...;` to `const guessElement = document.querySelector(".guess");`.  In your click handler, begin with `const guessInput = +(guessElement.value);`

Comment: I moved ```guessInput = Number(document.querySelector(".guess").value);``` into the function and have error: script.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: message is not defined;
Why it's undefined if I assigned it in global scope?

Comment: Thank you to everyone!! I sorted it. I didn't know that ```const guessElement = document.querySelector(".guess");``` should be assigned inside of function

Comment: @ZulfiyaYumagulova - the element can be assigned outside the function, but the value must be interrogated inside the function, because we want to know what the value is *after* the click happens.

Comment: @danh thank you to make it clear!! Now I understood.